# Removing simple object from JSON request

Tags: java, json

I wrote a small code to validate that my request fails when some part of it is removed.I want to remove the product element and its value.

Here's the request

```
{
    "product": "tv",
    "price": "45",
    "payment": {
        "credit_card": {
            "number": "1234567891234567",
            "type": "Visa",
            "expire_month": 10,
            "expire_year": 2019,
            "cvv2": 999,
            "first_name": "John",
            "last_name": "Smith"
        }
    }
}
```

This is the code snippet -

```
        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();

        String requestFile = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/src/test/resources/request/request.json";
        logger.info("Loading request file: " + requestFile);
        Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader(requestFile));

        JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;        

        //fails on the below line saying Java.lang.String cannot be cast to org.json.simple.JSONObject
       // What's the alternative?
        logger.info("printing json object "+jsonObject.get("product"));
        jsonObject = (JSONObject) jsonObject.remove("product");

        System.out.println("Now the request is "+jsonObject);
```

Comment: Which JSON library are you using?

Comment: JSONObject forwards the remove to its internal Map, and its `remove(...)` method returns the removed value, which is [a plain string of the keys value ("tv" in particular)](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html#remove%28java.lang.String%29). Therefore casting the String to JSONObject fails. Have you checked that `jsonObject` contains the entry after calling `remove(...)`? Remove the assignment to jsonObject and the cast therefore

Comment: @KDM json-lib-2.2.3-jdk15.jar in the pom file

Comment: You might be clubbing together two different JSON libraries. The standard json lib does not have a JSONParser. You construct the JSONObject by passing it a string which internally it parses. gson has JsonParser which returns a JsonObject. Can you check whether this is the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this problem. 
Here's the code snippet after making changes in it.

```
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();

        String requestFile = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/src/test/resources/request/original_request.json";
        logger.info("Loading request file: " + requestFile);
        Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader(requestFile));

        Object jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;

        //remove product_name
         ((HashMap) jsonObject).remove("product");

        logger.info("New request "+jsonObject);
```